# Error in iOS build on Codemagic: "Module 'cloud_firestore' not found"

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, codemagic

I am having an issue with the iOS build of my Flutter app on Codemagic. I get the following error:

```
    Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.example.meatcheat for device (ios-release)...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Removing script build phase dependency analysis.
Running pod install...                                             503ms
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           52.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8
Encountered error while building for device.
```

The error appears by the 4th step "building iOS..."

I am very sure cloud_firestore is added in my pub.

My pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end
```

Here's what I've tried so far to resolve the issue:

Set the Flutter version in Codemagic to "stable".
Updated the Podfile in the iOS folder and committed the Podfile.lock to my repository.
Attempted to run the pod install command in Codemagic before the build.
Tried different approaches to updating the Podfile.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve the issue yet. Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I could try to fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

NOTE: I am using a windows PC for that!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, tried following steps and it worked for me,

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

 pod deintegrate

 pod cache clean --all

 rm Podfile
```

delete podfile.lock file and install pod again
this should work fine

Comment: Did you use windows? On my computer the command sudo doesn't exist.

Comment: I use mac, its for ios development

Comment: ye, my question was how do i deploy it on windows.

Comment: You cant do it on windows, need MacBook only

Comment: So you mean there is really not a single way to deploy a iOS App without a mac?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the manual Podfile that i had created in ios folder of my flutter app.
Put those commands in pre-build script : 
`rm -rf ios; flutter create .`
And the build succeed.